# Trouble when reading data into buffer using mqqueue

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, pthreads, mqueue

I'm using [mqueue](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) to communicate between threads and I'm having a problem passing objects.

The `mq_send` and `mq_receive` take a `char*` as a parameter for the object.

I use them the following way.

```
foo* foo = new foo();
foo->set_id(3);
mq_send(myQueue, (char*)foo, 1024, 1);
```

then

```
char* buffer;
while(true)
{
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    bytes_read = mq_receive(myQueue, buffer, 1024, NULL);
    foo* foo = (foo*) buffer;
    foo->get_id(); //equals 3
    //Send the object to another queue
    mq_send(myOtherQueue, buffer, 1024, 1);
}
```

So far so good.

The problem is here

```
    char* buffer;
    while(true)
    {
        ssize_t bytes_read;
        bytes_read = mq_receive(myOtherQueue, buffer, 1024, NULL);
        foo* foo = (foo*) buffer;
        foo->get_id(); //equals garbage 323234234
    }
```

The second time I cast the buffer, I get garbage.
I read about `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` and I can't find what's the problem.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two issues here. First, is your Foo `TriviallyCopyable`?

Second,

```
char* buffer;
bytes_read = mq_receive(myOtherQueue, buffer, 1024, NULL);
```

I do not see any allocation for `buffer`.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyA. I don't understand your second point. mq_receive sets the buffer variable

Comment: @Marc, no, it copies data to the buffer provided. But your buffer is not allocated.

Comment: Is it not done in mq_receive based on the lenght (1024)?

Comment: Basically, all I want is share an address to an object between multiple threads

Comment: No, it is not done. It expects an allocated buffer (as every other similar function). Also, using mq in intra-process communication is a terrible waste of efficiency. It is am IPC mechanism.

Comment: I'm new to C++. Could you give me an example and what would you use instead of mq_queue?

Comment: You need to start looking for thread queues. There is plenty of material out there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just don't understand why it works for the first cast but not the second one

Comment: @Marc It was already explained - you didn't allocate any memory for your `buffer`, and didn't even initialize it - it will point to an indeterminate location in memory, hence writing data to it is Undefined behavior (it may _appear_ to work, or it may not).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No buffer points to foo*, it's not undefined

Comment: @Marc No, it doesn't. Please Re-read the answer, and all of the comments again. Since I don't plan to repeating myself over, and over again.

Comment: You are right. It works when I do char buffer[1024]. I just don't understand why it was working in the first thread.